# angular vs jquery for my project

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ejs

I have started developing a quiz application using angular that I have just learned. The project is 70% complete. But now I start to realize the ugly side of angular, behind the scenes where it watches for 100's of variables for change and updates, it seems like little or nothing has changed. This is really unacceptable and I feel jquery(I am proficient in), with templating engine like ejs I can make the application more fast, in fact the fastest it can get (compared to angular). I hate the idea of wasting cpu and memory on a smart phone when it is done performing the SO CALLED MAGIC OF ANGULAR. I have reduced the watches by optimization techniques, but still I don't feel good about it? What should I do? I mean, what I feel is real right? Should I throw away angular and restart on jquery. I have all the time in the world. Or should I try something like backbone(I dont know much about it), but I hear there are a little of magic.

Comment: I prefer to not to switch your framework. You might get same difficulties in another techniques as well when you will complete your project 60 - 70 %. You should sit down, be calm and think how to fix it now in the same technology. Nothing personal its just a simple think :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are saying that angular updates lot of variable and change it frequently but still there are lot of features available in angular which can't be find in jquery . you can look checkout this link

https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/jquery-angularjs-comparison-migration-walkthrough

Comment: i am marking you are right answer....despite the issues that show up with large projects...there is still magic in angular....besides it is by google....not  by microsoft who dares release software as crappy as IE

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment of Vineet; I don't think you should restart your project with an other technology, you will for sure face different issues that you didn't have for example with Angular.

Basically, I don't think angular is "slow"; If it is, it maybe means you are using it for an  heavy application when your data are refreshed all the time.

If yes, maybe you should check this post, the OP is giving some good tips on how to improve angular performances in these cases:

http://blog.500tech.com/is-reactjs-fast/

Also, if you want something fast (or at least, a reactive UI), I would recommend to use React instead of Backbone, but here again you will face others issues that you may not like, the design of react being quite different of other javascript framework and might look disturbing at first.

Comment: You are right.....i am sticking with it...looks like it was my over concern about performance.....i was able to reduce watches from 1500 to less than 500 and decent digest times. So its okay....my application is not actually big...somewhere between small and medium..

Answer (score 0):

We can not compare pigs with velocity ;)

Angular is framework javascript based. So... it uses javascript to output itself in a programatic and modular thinking.

On the other side jQuery is a library designed to write less javascript and reduce page latency.

In Angular you have a modular javascript framework and in jQuery you have a highly optimised javascript library.